# How to add context menu option to start a program in the given working directory

Tags: r, windows, registry, contextmenu, right-click

When you install Git on windows, it adds a context menu option when you right-click on a folder to "Git Bash Here". The way it does this is by adding a registry key like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%1\""
```

Notice the `cd` argument at the end that passes the directory name to the program.

I would like to do something similar for R (and other programs). Unfortunately R doesn't accept a `cd` argument. This will launch R:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\R\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.3\\bin\\x64\\Rgui.exe\" \"--cd=%1\""
```

but it gives an error message saying the `cd` argument is not recognized, and Rgui will start with whatever the default working directory is, defeating the entire point.

What I really want it to do is the equivalent of this command:

```
start "R" /D %1 "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64\Rgui.exe"
```

where `%1` is the folder that was right-clicked on. Is this possible?

Comment: Might be a better question for https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write R code that runs on startup and checks the commandline arguments.
You can put the following code at the end of `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\etc\Rprofile.site` (or any other file that gets executed at startup):

```
local({

  processArg <- function(arg) {
    parts <- strsplit(arg, "=")[[1]]
    if (length(parts) == 2) {
      if (parts[1] == "R_startup_wd") {
        setwd(parts[2])
      }
    }
  }

  invisible(sapply(commandArgs(FALSE), processArg))
})
```

It checks if R was called with an argument `R_startup_wd=your_working_dir` and changes the working directory if yes.
You can then call R like

`"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64\Rgui.exe" "R_startup_wd=your_working_dir"`

Note that the argument name is given without "--", i.e. we have `R_startup_wd` and not `--R_startup_wd`. Otherwise RGui will complain about "unknown arguments"

You can of course still use R without the argument given.